# Plot Trajectory in Matlab with quiver

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot a trajectory in Matlab with quiver. This is the code the Vectorfield.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:0.5:2);

xfield = Y.^2
yfield = X.^2

figure
quiver(X,Y,xfield,yfield);
```

Now I'd like to plot a path through this field with y = x-1, however I cloudn't find any tutorial for this on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold the axis and it's limits, then use `plot`:

```
hold on
axis manual
plot(xlim,xlim-1)
```